# How to prevent Popup losing focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, lostfocus

I have a `Combobox` defined in a data template of an `ItemsControl.` This `ComboBox` has a `Button` defined in it. On the `Button_Click` event, a `Popup` should be shown. This `Popup` contain a custom `UserControl` that has some controls defined inside it.

Here is the code before I explain my problem:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Width="140" Visibility="{Binding HasCombobox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
       <CompositeCollection>
           <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
           <ComboBoxItem>
              <Button Click="Button_Click" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Content="{x:Static prop:Resources.INSERT_BTN}"/>
           </ComboBoxItem>
       </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

This is the `Button_Click` event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button s = sender as Button;
    var popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
    popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
    popup.Child = new myCustomView();
    popup.PlacementTarget = s;
    popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
    popup.StaysOpen = true;
}
```

The problem is that when I click any of the controls defined inside `myCustomView` the `Popup` loses the focus and closes. How can I force it to stay opened?

**EDIT 1 :**

Since `myCustomView` has its own `ViewModel` I tried to hack the `Popup` to stay open by binding its `IsOpen` property to a boolean inside the view model like this:

```
popup.DataContext = myCustomViewModel;
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = myCustomViewModel;
b.Path = new PropertyPath("stayOpened");
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Default;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(popup, Popup.IsOpenProperty, b);
// BindingOperations.SetBinding(popup, Popup.StaysOpenProperty, b);  tried both IsOpened and StaysOpen
```

But the focus switch still kills my `Popup`.

Comment: What's the difference between this question and your previous one?

Comment: Because now i have a specific problem regarding the lose of the focus. The previous question was about on how actually i could show a view inside the Popup. The target of the question is changed, in my opinion.

Comment: @mm8 it worked. You can post that part here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `PlacementTarget` to the parent `ItemsControl` and then set the `VerticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset` properties of the `Popup` to specify its exact location on the screen, e.g.:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button s = sender as Button;
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup popup = new System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup();
    popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
    popup.Child = new myCustomView();
    //some stuff needed to recognise which button was pressed
    popup.PlacementTarget = ic; //<-- "ic" is the name of the parent ItemsControl
    Point p = s.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), ic);
    popup.VerticalOffset = p.Y; //adjust this value to fit your requirements
    popup.HorizontalOffset = p.X; //adjust this value to fit your requirements
    popup.IsOpen = true;
    popup.StaysOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: It works. Just for the sake of completition, to place the popup on the button it is sufficient to do this :  

    `popup.VerticalOffset = p.Y - myCustomView.Height;`  and
    `popup.HorizontalOffset = p.X - myCustomView.Width;`

Answer (score 0):

You could set [Popup.StaysOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.staysopen(v=vs.110).aspx) to true like this

```
<Popup StaysOpen="True"/>
```

Comment: Unless it has a different effect, i have already did that in the event `Button_Click`:   `popup.IsOpen = true;`  . And it works, cause i can click on the background of myCustomIView without the Popup being closed. The problem is the change of focus